# d3.js onclick event uses the value of variable at time of click instead of at time of drawing

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm drawing a set of circles on an SVG Container using d3.js.
I have an `eventList`. For each element in this list, I draw a circle. Here is how I do it. It works:

```
var eventList = [
    Object {stateId: 5},
    Object {stateId: 6},
    Object {stateId: 7},
];
for (var i = 0; i <= eventList.length-1; i++) {
  var currEvent = eventList[i];

  var myCircle = self.svgContainer.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", i * 100)
    .attr("cy", i * 100)
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("stroke-width", 0)
    .attr("fill", "red");
}
```

I'm now trying to add on-click behavior to each of these circles. I want clicking on each circle to take me to a specific URL based on data found in the eventList. Here's what I'm adding into the loop above:

```
    myCircle.on({
        "click":  function() {
          console.log("Hello! currEvent.stateId=", currEvent.stateId.toString());
          console.log("currEvent = ", currEvent);
          $state.go('myState', {
              'stateId': currEvent.stateId
            }
          );
        }
      }
    );
```

By my understanding, this should work. But it doesn't. What it does is run the onclick code when I click on any of the circles. At that point it prints out the value of `currentEvent.stateId` -- **which is always the last one!**. So clicking on every circle simply takes me to the same URL - which should only happen when clicking the last circle.

How do I make it so the onclick code uses the value of currentEvent at the time when that circle was drawn, rather than when the click is actually fired? This is a big issue for me.

Comment: please show the structure of your `eventList` variable

Comment: I have updated my question to show eventList.

Comment: I hope this code `myCircle.on({` is also inside the for loop. Now when the click event is fired the variable `currEvent` will hold the last value.
This is not the way to register data with circles. You should be using `data` `enter` to make circle and bind the data with it.

Comment: Cyril. Thanks. Can you show me how to use `data` `enter`? I was unaware. I just saw this onclick code and grabbed it thinking it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when you are executing the click event the variable `currEvent` will have the last value which is your problem.

The correct approach would be to bind the data to the circle.

```
var myCircle = svg.selectAll(".dots")
.data(eventList).enter().append("circle")//make as many circle as their are events in the eventList. This will bind the data to  the circle.
  .attr("class", "dots")//set a class to circle for selection to work
  .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
    return (i * 100)
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d, i) {
    return (i * 100)
  })
  .attr("r", 5)
  .attr("stroke-width", 0)
  .attr("fill", "red");
```

Now register click event to all circles.

```
myCircle.on({
  "click": function(d) {
    //here d will give the bound object 
    console.log("Hello! currEvent.stateId=", d.stateId.toString());
    console.log("currEvent = ", d);
  }
});
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/mvveu45e/)

Comment: Thanks for your example @Cyril! But I'm not sure this method will work for me. I need to iterate through the eventList in a loop because there are a number of other things (not shown in my original question) that I need to do in the loop for each event. For example, calculating the X and Y values of the circle is actually a lot more complicated than I explained. I also need to draw some lines based on those X & Y coordinates. Can you show me how I might be able to do this iterating over `eventList` with a for loop?

Comment: OK if you are calculating X and Y in a loop go ahead do it and set the X/Y value into eventlist.
Now when you making the circle using `.data(eventList)` make use of the value calculated above `.attr("cx", function(d, i) {
    return d.X;//this was calculated and stored in eventList
  })`